# How do I map a route that it will give the last url an output of 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a custom route in the RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapRoute(
             "Category3",
             "category/{action}/{top}/{middle}/{category}",
            new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", top = UrlParameter.Optional, middle = UrlParameter.Optional, category = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And my categoryController looks like

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Category/

    public string Get(string top, string middle, string category)
    {
        return top + "/" + middle +  "/" + category;

    }

}
```

All works well for

```
/category/get/1/2/3 gives output 1/2/3

/category/get/1/2 gives output 1/2
```

but

```
/category/get/1 gives output ""
```

How do I map a route that it will give the last url an output of 1?

The endgoal is to get urls like

```
/category/get/main/sub/category
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if this is a routing problem or is your string concatenation failing because you're trying to append a null string?

Comment: it is a routing problem because the /category/get/1 hits the the get method but the parameter top has the value null.

Comment: Can you set a break point and see what the values of top middle and category are for the case 1/2?  It seems like if it was working correctly it would have given output "1/2/" not "1/2"

Answer (score 1):

Is this route below the default route?  If so, you're probably executing the `Index` action.  Routes are processed in order from top to bottom, and first match wins.

Comment: the route is below the the default route. If you paste the route above and an empty project and add the control you can reproduce the behaviour.